# Unable to insert data into second table in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

``I am using `SQLite` Database.I have created two tables.first table is user table ,it is successfully create and inserted.but in my second table also successfully created but does not insert.this is my problem.Thank for advances..

This is OnClick event here try to call the insert method which is present in the database class

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String itemname;
    String price;
    int position;
    if(v.getId()==R.id.id_btn_submit){
        //insert the price into database
            itemname =mEditItemName.getText().toString();
            price =(mEditPrice.getText().toString());
            position=spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

        if(itemname.isEmpty()){
            mEditItemName.setError("enter the item name");

        }else if(price.isEmpty()){
            mEditPrice.setError("pls enter the price");
        }else{
            dataBase=new DataBase(this);
            position=position+1;
            mItemId= dataBase.insertAll(itemname,price, String.valueOf(position));
        }
        mEditItemName.setText("");
        mEditPrice.setText("");
      Log.d("bucky ","succefully insert ");

    }
```

This is insert method

```
 public long insertAll(String itemname ,String price,String itemcategory){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues content=new ContentValues();
    content.put(databasehelper.mITEMNAME, itemname);
    content.put(databasehelper.mITEMPRICE, price);
    content.put(databasehelper.mITEMCATEGORY, itemcategory);
    long id=sqLiteDatabase.insert(databasehelper.mTABLEMENUITEM,null,content);
    Log.d("bucky insert item", String.valueOf(id));
    return id;
}
```

create Statement and update Statement

```
 public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private final static String mDATABASENAME="foodpanta";
    private final static int mVERSION=9;
    private Context context;
    //user  information table
    private final static String mTABLEUSERDETAIL="userdetail";
    private final static String mUID="_id";
    private final static String mUSERNAME="username";
    private final static String mUSERMAIL="usermail";
    private final static String mUSERPASS="userpass";
    private final static String mUSERMOBILE="usermobile";
    private final static String mCREATETABLEUSER ="CREATE TABLE " + mTABLEUSERDETAIL +" ("+mUID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +mUSERNAME+" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "+mUSERMAIL+" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "+mUSERPASS+" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "+mUSERMOBILE+" VARCHAR(255));";

    //Adding menu item table
    private final static String mTABLEMENUITEM="menuitem";
    private final static String mITEMID="_id";
    private final static String mITEMCATEGORY="item category";
    private final static String mITEMPRICE="itemprice";
    private final static String mITEMNAME="itemname";
    private final static String mCREATETABLEMENU="CREATE TABLE " + mTABLEMENUITEM +" ("+mITEMID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +mITEMNAME+" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "+mITEMPRICE+" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "+mITEMCATEGORY+" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);";
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, mDATABASENAME, null, mVERSION);
        this.context=context;
        Message.message(context,"on constructor called");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(mCREATETABLEUSER);

        db.execSQL(mCREATETABLEMENU);
        Message.message(context, "on create called");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + mTABLEUSERDETAIL);

         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + mTABLEMENUITEM);
        Message.message(context, "on upgrade  called");
        onCreate(db);

    }

}

Stack Trace:
12-09 17:13:45.698 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>
12-09 17:13:46.085 672-672/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History>
12-09 17:13:46.086 672-672/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History>
12-09 17:13:48.801 672-672/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History>
12-09 17:13:48.802 672-672/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History>
12-09 17:13:51.138 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "category": syntax error
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting item category=1 itemprice=59 itemname= bzb
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "category": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO menuitem(item category,itemprice,itemname) VALUES (?,?,?)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1492)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1364)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at com.example.node10.foodcourt.DataBase.insertAll(DataBase.java:72)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at com.example.node10.foodcourt.ItemAdd.onClick(ItemAdd.java:75)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5300)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:830)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:646)
12-09 17:13:51.140 15388-15388/com.example.node10.foodcourt E/SQLiteDatabase:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you post your stacktrace?

Comment: I debug the code and i found that id value is -1.

Comment: That is because it didn't inserted. Insert returns you the PK value of the inserted value.

Comment: Ya I know the value didn't insert.what mistake i have done?

Comment: Post your stacktrace please.

Comment: @Fustigador i post it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO menuitem(item category,itemprice,itemname) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

There is your error, "item category" should be "itemcategory", you added a space somewhere, and sqlite thinks you are trying to insert four values instead of three.

Specifically, here:

```
private final static String mITEMCATEGORY="item category";
```